# How to optimize this code and remove the for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I try to optimize this for loop. I can't find a way to only use vectorization.

Here the small dataframe

```
         atr  short_stop  long_stop  shortStopPrev  longStopPrev  dir
0        NaN         NaN        NaN            NaN           NaN    1
1   0.000742    0.385232   0.384119            NaN           NaN    1
2   0.001954    0.385232   0.384119       0.385232      0.384119   -1
3   0.001238    0.386438   0.384581       0.385232      0.384119    1
4   0.001854    0.386438   0.384776       0.386438      0.384581    1
5   0.000766    0.386438   0.385564       0.386438      0.384776    1
6   0.001504    0.386438   0.385564       0.386438      0.385564   -1
7   0.001168    0.387331   0.385579       0.386438      0.385564    1
8   0.001520    0.387331   0.385579       0.387331      0.385579    1
9   0.001222    0.386843   0.385579       0.387331      0.385579    1
10  0.001032    0.386604   0.385579       0.386843      0.385579    1
11  0.001550    0.386604   0.385579       0.386604      0.385579    1
12  0.001208    0.386189   0.384377       0.386604      0.385579    1
13  0.001014    0.386189   0.384994       0.386189      0.384377    1
14  0.001832    0.386189   0.384994       0.386189      0.384994    1
15  0.001382    0.385783   0.384994       0.386189      0.384994    1
16  0.001888    0.385783   0.383515       0.385783      0.384994    1
17  0.000810    0.385772   0.384428       0.385783      0.383515    1
18  0.001178    0.385772   0.384512       0.385772      0.384428    1
19  0.001050    0.385772   0.384577       0.385772      0.384512    1
```

Here the code

```py
def CE_exit(dataframe, length=14, mult=2.0):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=dataframe.index)
    df['atr'] = ta.ATR(dataframe['high'], dataframe['low'], dataframe['close'], timeperiod=length)
    df['atr'] = df['atr'] * mult
    #
    # # Calculate short stop and long stop using rolling functions
    df['short_stop'] = dataframe['low'].rolling(length).min() + df['atr']
    df['long_stop'] = dataframe['high'].rolling(length).max() - df['atr']

    df['shortStopPrev'] = df['short_stop']
    df['longStopPrev'] = df['long_stop']
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        df['shortStopPrev'][i] = df['short_stop'][i-1]
        if dataframe['close'][i - 1] < df['shortStopPrev'][i]:
            df.at[i, 'short_stop'] = min(df['shortStopPrev'][i], df['short_stop'][i])
        else:
            df.at[i, 'short_stop'] = df['short_stop'][i]

        df['longStopPrev'][i] = df['long_stop'][i-1]
        if dataframe['close'][i - 1] > df['longStopPrev'][i]:
            df.at[i, 'long_stop'] = max(df['longStopPrev'][i], df['long_stop'][i])
        else:
            df.at[i, 'long_stop'] = df['long_stop'][i]

    df['dir'] = 1  # Assume long by default
    df['dir'] = np.where(dataframe['close'] > df['short_stop'], -1, df['dir'])
    df['dir'] = np.where(dataframe['close'] < df['long_stop'], 1, df['dir'])
    return df
```

How to remove the for loop ? is it possible to remove it ? I want to optimize the execution of this loop.

Comment: Why don't you describe the rules for us in words?  Often, describing the problem leads to a solution.

Comment: Agreed with @TimRoberts, though it at least looks like df.shift() may be useful for you (i.e. you can create a new column that is offset by 1 which allows you to compare rows to previous rows)

Comment: `df.at[i, 'short_stop'] = df['short_stop'][i]` and `df.at[i, 'long_stop'] = df['long_stop'][i]` are useless isn't it? It seems like a `var = var` statement. If so, you can remove them.

Comment: Accessing item from both the column and the row is known to be very very slow. You can extract the whole column and then get the ith item. It is still slow but certainly much better. It make the loop more readable IMHO. Last but not least, you can more easily detect pattern and iteratively convert parts of the loop to Numpy operations. When this is not possible, you can use Numba or Cython (assuming items are mostly numbers). The later should be at least 2 or 3 order of magnitude faster than the current code.